# Opa session error

Tags: debugging, opa

I've got the following error with my opa application :

```
[SESSION] Uncaught exception: "{OpaRPC_Server: {timeout: {client: {client: $"s2jtpj3tbyztpfbrm3gf8bd2k7kcnxg1"$; page: $
896774575$}; fun_id: $"_v0_get_value_stdlib.core.xhtml"$}}}"
  The following message is skipped.:
    If you want (msg, st, ctx) debug printing set debug variable session_debug >= 200C
```

What does it mean ?

Answer (score 0):

That means two things you have a server sessions which calls a client function, but the client doesn't reply to the server.

1 - When a client doesn't reply to the server, the client calls raise an Opa exception "OpaRPC_Server" after a timeout. 
That can happen in several cases (client runtime error, client leaves the application, etc.).
In your case the server try to call the client function identified by "_v0_get_value_stdlib.core.xhtml" (Dom.get_value?)

2 - When an exception is not catch on a session handler, the session catch the exception, throw the current message and the session is released to process future messages.

Be aware that when you make (a standard) session, the message handler is a critical section.

Comment: I have another question. How can I stop the program when the user close is tab/window ?